# Why does the python strtobool method return an Int instead of a bool?

Tags: python

[strtobool](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=distutils.util#distutils.util.strtobool) is a great function from the python standard library.

However it returns an int instead of a bool, requiring wrapping it eg `bool(strtobool(x))`.

On the surface, this seems unintuitive and misleading, and it's very easy to forget especially in a loosely typed language like python.
What were the design decisions which led to this approach?

Comment: What's the difference, why would you need to wrap it? bools are just a subclass of ints anyway. `if strtobool(x)` will behave just like `if bool(strtobool(x))`? Do you have an example were it makes an actual difference?

Comment: It creates code warnings when using type hinting.  It also breaks any code that uses `isinstance(x, bool)`.  But even if not using type hinting, and if writing/using better code that doesn't use `isinstance`, it seems an unexpected implementation detail to create a method called `strtobool` that returns an `int`.  The answer may just be "there's no good design reason, the guy who wrote it just decided to" but I suspect there's someone on here that knows of some important detail that influenced the decision.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why `strtobool()` returns an int. An int can be used as a bool in most situations, however, if you actually need a bool then I would recommend that you create a new function within your scripts that looks something like this:

```py
from distutils.util import strtobool as stb
def strtobool(string: str)->bool: return bool(stb(string))
```

This allows calling `strtobool()` so it returns an bool.

Answer (score 1):

It's *probably* anyone's guess at this point. `distutils` is deprecated and being removed in Python 3.12, as per [PEP 632](https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/), and regarding `strtobool` specifically, the advice is to re-implement it by yourself:

> For these functions, and any others not mentioned here, you will need to reimplement the functionality yourself. The legacy documentation can be found at https://docs.python.org/3.9/distutils/apiref.html
>
> - `distutils.dir_util.create_tree`
> - `distutils.util.change_root`
> - `distutils.util.strtobool`

So, in short, don't use it, and in your version, feel free to return a proper `bool` instead.